# Change Tracking of a specific column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, change-tracking

I have an important column (`Balance` property of `Account` table) in a SQL Server database. I track and log this property in my program but also I want to track and save changes of this column in the level of database. I don't want to tracking all properties of table because it is not important to me. Please help me to find a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a trigger to insert the change, insert or delete to a type of audit table.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189799(v=sql.110).aspx

```
CREATE TRIGGER yourInsertTrigger ON Account
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO yourAuditTable
        (balance, user_id, user_name)
    SELECT
        inserted.balance, user_id, user_name
        FROM inserted
go
```

A word of caution though, performance can become affected if you have too many triggers, the trigger actions are expensive or it is a table that is frequently updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can create history table:

**History**

```
account_ID
column_name
old_value
new_value
```

In that table you insert every changes with table **Account**.
For that you could use trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER account_UID on Account
FOR INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS
BEGIN
  -- for update
  INSERT INTO history (account_ID, column_name, old_value, new_value)
    SELECT I.account_ID, 'balance', D.balance, I.balance
      FROM inserted as I left join deleted as D on I.account_ID = D.account_ID
    where D.account_ID is not null and I.balance <> D.balance

  -- for insert
  INSERT INTO history (account_ID, column_name, old_value, new_value)
    SELECT I.account_ID, 'balance', null, I.balance
      FROM inserted as I left join deleted as D on I.account_ID = D.account_ID
    where D.account_ID is null

  -- for delete
  INSERT INTO history (account_ID, column_name, old_value, new_value)
    SELECT D.account_ID, 'balance', D.balance, null
      FROM deleted as D left join inserted as I on D.account_ID = I.account_ID
    where D.account_ID is not null
END
```

where clause is important because you need to insert  `null` in `old_value` when inserting new row and `null` ind `new_value` when deleting row

Sorry for my english.